# How to fix maximum call stack size exceeded in react native while making fetch request?

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am getting maximum call stack size exceeded while making a fetch POST call with form data.

I tried to log all the POST parameters nothing wrong there.

```
_addFU(){
    var url = 'https://'

    var fuData = JSON.stringify({
      fu_comment: this.state.comment,
      fu_type: this.state.paymentType,
      fu_status: this.state.status,
      fu_amout: this.state.amount,
      fu_follwup_on: this.state.dateText
    })

    var data = {
      key: this.state.key,
      secret_key: this.state.secretKey,
      asc_id: this.state.ascId,
      role_selected: this.state.roleId,
      fu_det: fuData
    }

    formData = new FormData()
    for(value in data){
      formData.append(value, data[value])
      console.log(value, data[value])
    }

    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }

    fetch(url, request)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {console.log(response.message)})
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

Maximum call stack size exceeded.

fetch
index.delta?platform-android&dev-true&minify-false:113465:47

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with fetch. it must be some other operations done after the fetch request-response is done.

Comment: Can you share your other codes that supposed to be run after the fetch response has come

Comment: @Siraj I am trying to log whatever response I am getting from API, but it's not printing anything and I am getting the above error. It's not executing anything after fetch call.

Comment: Showing more codes would help us to find the issue, as these codes seem fine to me.

Comment: @Siraj I updated my code. Please have a look.